# File I/O functions VB net

Tags: vb.net, file-io

Just have a few really simple questions about some VB net functions that aren't clear on MSDN:

1. When you use the **fileopen** function EG

   ```
   fileopen(1,Path of file,openmode.binary)
   ```

   ,how does the openmode.binary actually work when a ***text*** file is the
   file to be opened? Is each character used in binary form?
2. When you use a **fileget** function;

   ```
   fileget(1,variablename)
   ```

   ,does the variable type depend on what is read from the file? So if
   variablename was declared as a char, would the fileget function just
   read the characters from file?
3. Is the **fileclose** function used to simply improve *efficieny*? EG if
   not closed would be similar to an infinite loop?

Comment: You need to forget that these functions exist.  They were made to help a programmer port his VB6 program to .NET, they are not appropriate to use if you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't, you aren't supposed to do this. If you have a text file, you should open it in text mode, not binary mode. Binary mode is for reading in files that you wrote out in binary mode.
2. Yes, but you're expected to match the data types up correctly, based on how you initially wrote the data out to the file. If you get it wrong, all bets are off. There's nothing automatic here.
3. No, you don't close the file to improve efficiency, you close it because you're finished using it. Not closing the file causes a resource leak. The file won't be closed until your application is closed, then the operating system will automatically release it. I suppose you could consider leaking resources to be inefficient, but I don't think that's what you meant. It's nothing like an infinite loop. The app keeps running, the file just can't be opened or read by anything else because you have a lock on it.

But like everyone else has already said, **you really need to give up on these old, obsolete functions**. They hail from the earliest and darkest days of the BASIC programming language. You used to *have* to do things this way, but thank goodness we don't anymore. The only reason they exist in VB.NET at all is to make it easier to port old VB 6 applications. And even if that's what you're doing, part of your porting effort should involve switching over to the functions provided by the `System.IO` namespace. It's not just about being idiomatic or using the latest and greatest just for the sake of it, it's about saving yourself a lot of extra work and pain.

Answer (score 3):

NET Framework has a namespace called [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) full of methods to read and write file (text or binary)

This sample [taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) is an example on how you read a text file with VB.NET

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Try 
        Using sr As New StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
            Dim line As String
            line = sr.ReadToEnd()
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        End Using 
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try 
End Sub
```

Here the fileopen function is replaced by the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aetdk20.aspx) constructor. The fileget is replaced by the `ReadToEnd` (or `ReadLine` or `ReadBlock`) method of the StreamReader, while the closing of the file is replaced by the End Using istruction that close and destroy the StreamReader object created by the initial Using.

I suggest to read this article on MSDN: [Common I/O tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the input, i'm aware of using streamreaders and streamwriters but i'm just needing some input for the functions i stated.

Comment: I'm sorry for you, really, you should leave these functions behind and use what has been specifically designed for the NET.